# Relative images broken, need javascript fix

Tags: javascript, html, image, replace

new here. I have no access to most of the source files on my website, so I am trying to fix some broken images  on page load with javascript.

When I use the inspect element for one of these broken images it shows like this:

```
<img src="-82.jpg" width="60px">
```

when they should be

```
<img src="http://example.com/files/images/-82.jpg" width="60px">
```

This is for bunch of different images, -82.jpg,  -2482.jpg, -3582.jpg

Here's what I have tried so far.  This seems to work but for some reason it breaks other javascript on the page.

---

**html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/files/js/fiximages.js"></script>
<body onload="fixImages();">
```

**my fiximages.js file**

```
function fixImages() {
    var toReplace = '<img src="-';
    var replaceWith ='<img src="http://www.example.com/files/images/-';
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(toReplace, replaceWith);
}
```

I'm a bit of a noob so I also need to know how to link the html to the javascript to get it to load when the page loads.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Are you allowed to use JQuery?

Comment: @Bonatoc I don't think it's a good idea to load a whole library to achieve such a small task.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It was late and I was feeling kinda lazy. Since he's a noobie, he would have learned some JQuery as well. I agree we are leaning towards pure Javascript web apps nowadays. BTW I voted for your answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
function fixImages() {
    // Create a list of all img which src starts with "-".
    var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img[src^="-"]');

    // Loop through this list.
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        // For each img, replace its src with the correct path + the
        // src that's already there.
        imgs[i].setAttribute('src', 'http://www.example.com/files/images/' + imgs[i].getAttribute('src'));
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/pxdte5b7/1/)

Comment: If you want the script to run just when the whole page is loaded, including all the images, refer to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload

Comment: Marked as solved, and thanks for the link.  I've been wondering how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

The problem in your approach is that changing the body's pure HTML is never a good idea for a dynamic page. Also, javascript's `replace`, when used without a regex, is going to replace only the first ocurrence of the string.

Now, when you need to change an element's attribute, Javascript has a manipulation called DOM. There are plenty material and tutorials on the web... You should look into it!

- http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp

With DOM, you can select an element as a variable, and manipulate its properties and attributes, so, in your case it would be:

```
function fixImages() {
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
        if(imgs[i].src.indexOf("-") == 0)
            imgs[i].src = "http://www.example.com/files/images/" + imgs[i].src;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just added the check for it... Anyway, +1 to you for using `querySelector`

Comment: I removed the comment because you edited the answer in the same moment. :)